# How to create a custom dataset generator with multiple inputs and one label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I've written a python script for loading a large dataset (I cannot load them directly) and feed it to a Keras model.
the custom dataset is written as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomDataSequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_set, gender,Slice,Type, label_set, batch_size=32, image_size=(256, 256)):
        self.image_set = np.array(image_set)
        self.Gender = gender
        self.Slice = Slice
        self.Type = Type
        self.label_set = label_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.image_size = image_size
    def __get_image(self, image):
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image, color_mode='rgb', target_size=self.image_size)
        image_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
        return image_arr/255

    def __get_data(self, images, gender,Slice,Type, labels):
        image_batch = np.asarray([self.__get_image(img) for img in images])
        label_batch = labels
        Gender_batch = gender
        Slice_batch = Slice
        Type_batch = Type
        return [image_batch, Gender_batch, Slice_batch, Type_batch], label_batch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        images = self.image_set[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        Gender = self.Gender[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        Slice = self.Slice[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        Type = self.Type[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        labels = self.label_set[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        data, labels = self.__get_data(images, Gender,Slice,Type, labels)
        return data, labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_set) // self.batch_size + (len(self.image_set) % self.batch_size > 0)
```

As you can see, there are some input variables (image_batch, Gender_batch, Slice_batch, Type_batch). In the mail part of my code I create two objects for training and validation dataset:

```
train_ds = CustomDataSequence(Train,Train_G,Train_S,Train_T, Train_y, image_size=(80,80), batch_size=32)
val_ds = CustomDataSequence(Validation,Val_G,Val_S,Val_T, Val_y, image_size=(80,80), batch_size=32)
```

And my model is:

```
model = ResNet50(input_shape = IMAGE_SIZE,include_top = False, weights = '/content/RadImageNet-ResNet50_notop.h5')
for layer in model.layers[0:len(model.layers)-30]:
     layer.trainable = False
inputB = Input(shape=(1,))
inputC = Input(shape=(Val_S.shape[1],))
inputD = Input(shape=(Val_T.shape[1],))
model_output = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(model.output)
model_output = concatenate([model_output, inputB,inputC,inputD])
model_output = Dense(64, activation='relu')(model_output)
model_output = Dense(32, activation='relu')(model_output)
model_output = Dense(16, activation='relu')(model_output)
model_output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(model_output)
model=Model(inputs=[model.input,inputB,inputC,inputD],outputs=model_output)
```

And then I feed these datasets to my model by this code:

```
model.fit(train_ds,validation_data=val_ds, callbacks=callbacks , epochs=40,verbose = 1)
```

Unfortunately, an error was raised:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was ((TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32), SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None]), tf.float32)), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)), but the yielded element was ((array([[[[0.4392157 , 0.4392157 , 0.4392157 ],
         [0.4862745 , 0.4862745 , 0.4862745 ],
         [0.52156866, 0.52156866, 0.52156866],
         ...,
         [0.8784314 , 0.8784314 , 0.8784314 ],
         [0.8901961 , 0.8901961 , 0.8901961 ],
         [0.9019608 , 0.9019608 , 0.9019608 ]],

        [[0.49019608, 0.49019608, 0.49019608],
         [0.53333336, 0.53333336, 0.53333336],
         [0.56078434, 0.56078434, 0.56078434],
         ...,
```

I've tried using a dictionary but it didn't work. it's good to mention that my code when I feed just an image to model as input work correctly and when I use multiple input I encounter with this problem.

Comment: Note that the inputB not caused problem. vector inputs (inputC , inputD) are making problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).